# How to write a function to count number of possible binary relations of 5 elements which are asymmetric and transitive

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math, mathematical-optimization

I have 5 values:

```
A={1,2,3,4,5}
```

I consider binary relations of them, so i have a matrix

```
     1     2      3     4      5
1  (1,1) (1,2) (1,3)  (1,4)  (1,5)
2  (2,1) (2,2) (2,3)  (2,4)  (2,5)
3  (3,1) (3,2) (3,3)  (3,4)  (3,5)
4  (4,1) (4,2) (4,3)  (4,4)  (4,5)
5  (5,1) (5,2) (5,3)  (5,4)  (5,5)
```

How could I count all possible combinations of those values when they are asymmetric (f.e. if there is (1,2) there shouldn't be (2,1) and no duplicates (1,1),(2,2),...) and transitive (f.e. if there is (2,3) and (3,5) there also should be (2,5)).
How to write a function to count all possible variations of those relations?

Comment: I don't quite understand the objectives. Can you give a full example with say, just 4 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

`len(A)!` will give you all the possibilities without symmetrical combinations but with duplicates, you can then subtract the number of duplicates `len(A)`

```
(len(A))!-len(A)
```

the equation can be simplified to:

```
(len(A)-1)!
```